# Describe the set of all good numbers

Tags: divisibility

A natural number $k$ is considered good, if for each $n$ the number $1^k+2^k+\cdots+n^k$ is divisible by $1+2 +\cdots+n$. Describe the set of all good numbers (with proof).

Comment: The problem seems to be from [here](http://taharut.org/students/S2008/StudentsStage2.PDF), and the answer is given [here](http://taharut.org/students/S2008/StudentsStage2solved.PDF).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen - thanks  a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know, $1+2+\cdots+(n-1)+n=\frac{n(n+1)}2$

As Thomas has pointed out  $3\not\mid(1+2^k)$ for even $k,$ so $k$ can not be even.

Now, $r^k+(n-r)^k\equiv r^k\{1+(-1)^k\} \pmod n$

So,  $r^k+(n-r)^k\equiv r^k(1-1)\equiv0\pmod n$ for all $r\in[0,n]$ if $k$ is odd

So, $n\mid\{r^k+(n-r)^k\}$ if and only if $k$ is odd

Putting $r=0,1,\cdots,n$ and summing them  we get $n\mid 2\sum_{1\le r\le n}r^k$

Again, $r^k+(n+1-r)^k\equiv r^k\{1+(-1)^k\} \pmod {n+1}$

So, $(n+1)\mid\{r^k+(n-r)^k\}$ if and only if $k$ is odd

Putting $r=0,1,\cdots,n+1$ and summing them  we get $(n+1)\mid 2\sum_{1\le r\le n+1}r^k\implies (n+1)\mid 2\sum_{1\le r\le n}r^k $

So, $lcm(n,n+1)\mid 2\sum_{1\le r\le n}r^k $ if and only if $k$ is odd

$\implies \frac{n(n+1)}2\mid \sum_{1\le r\le n}r^k $ if and only if $k$ is odd as gcd$(n,n+1)=$gcd$(n,1)=1\implies $lcm$(n,n+1)=n(n+1)$

Comment: Just because $n\not |r^k+(n-r)^k$, we can't conclude that $n\not|\sum (r^k+(n-r)^k$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, even if for all integer $n$ and $0\le r\le n?$

Comment: Well, it might just be easier to show that if $k$ is even, then $1+2^k$ is not divisible by $3$ :)

Comment: But I don't see how your attempt proves it. I think your result is right - the odd numbers are the only ones that satisfy this - but your proof essentially is for fixed $n$, and doesn't seem to use that it is true for all $n$ to reach a contradiction.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I'm not sure what you meant by fixed $n.$ The conclusion I've reached, will hold true for any positive integral value of $n,$ right? Also, included your logic to cancel out the even values of $k$

Comment: No, you've proved that, when $k$ is even, $n$ can't divide $r^k+(n-r)^k$, but you have not proved that, when $k$ is even, $n$ can't divide $\sum_{r=1}^k r^k +(n-r)^k$.  That second statement does not follow from the first statement. For example, it might be possible that $r^k+(n-r)^k\equiv 1\pmod n$. You haven't proven that can't happen. So you haven't proven anything in the case $k$ even. (As I say, it is easy to prove when $k$ even just by looking at $n=2$.)

Comment: For example, $1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2=30$ is divisible by $1+2+3+4=10$. So it is *not* true for any $n$. Indeed, when $k=2$, it doesn't work for any $n\equiv 1\pmod 3$.

Comment: (That was in ref to your original proof, which was correct for $k$ odd, but got confused when $k$ even. The edited version, which i did not notice, removes that error.)